# Función python - split

Tags: split

¡Hola!
Estoy utilizando pdfpumbler para obtener información de un PDF, y para obtener cierta información estoy utilizando la función split de la siguiente manera:
linea.split ('Emisión') [1]. split ('Folio') [0]

Sin embargo cuando corro el programa me manda el siguiente mensaje de error:

> File "C:\Comercial\FSG\LeePDFTable.py", line 24
> fecPedido = linea.split ('Fecha Emisi?n') [1] . split ('Folio') [0] SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf3,

Así que dentro del programa intento cambiando "Emisi\ón", "Emisi&oacute;n" "Emisión" pero marca error.
Alguna sugerencia de como puedo manejar la palabara Emisión dentro del programa?
El programa en Spyder Anacanda no marca el error, pero al realizar la ejecución en MS-DOS es donde lo marca!
Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Creo que se debe a cómo le indicas la ruta para leer el fichero, prueba colocando dobles barras de la siguiente manera:

```
"C:\\Comercial\\FSG\\LeePDFTable.py"
```

Otra forma de indicarle a python la ruta del archivo es añadirle una "r" a la ruta, se quedaría de esta forma:

```
("C:\\Comercial\\FSG\\LeePDFTable.py","r")
```